# $||\tilde{T}|| = ||T||$ for $\tilde{T}$ an extension of a lineal bounded operator.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T: D\to Y$ be a lineal operator where $D\subset X$ a normed space and $Y$ Banach.

I got that there exists a lineal operator $\tilde{T}\colon \overline{D}\to Y$ such that $\tilde{T}x = Tx$ for all $x\in D$. However, I don't know how to show that $||\tilde{T}|| = ||T||$.

I defined $\tilde{T}$ as follows: If $x\in\overline{D}$, then $\tilde{T}x = \lim Tx_n$ for $x_n\to x$. The existence of the limit of $T x_n$ is ensured by the Banach condition: since $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence since it is convergent, then $T x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, and thus there exists the limit.

Thank you.

Comment: It is a continuity of norm argument. You start from the norm of the limit and then show you get the limit of the norms.

Comment: The problem I found doing that is that I have to show that $||\tilde{T}|| = \sup \lim \frac{||Tx_n||}{||x_n||} = \lim \sup \frac{||Tx_n||}{||x_n||}= ||{T}|| = $, isn't it? Is it obvious that we can change the supremum and the limit?

Comment: There is an easier way to think about it: for any particular $x_n$ in $D$ converging to $x$ in $\overline{D}$, $\lim \| \tilde{T}x_n \| = \| \lim \tilde{T} x_n \| = \| \lim T x_n \|$. Now every $x \in \overline{D}$ is of the form $\lim x_n$ for some suitable sequence...

Comment: Oh, that is easier, yes. Thank you!